# When use iron-router, when did onRender is executed?

Tags: javascript, dom, meteor, iron-router, meteor-blaze

i am using iron-router and user can router between same templates with different data.
(same route! only route params change)

i need make manipulate on the DOM elements each time that data is changed.
when i put it on onRendered function it's running only at first route!!! or, if i arrive from another route!!!!

how can i force route to rerun the onRendered, or where should i write it to run again automatically when data is changed, **AFTER** the DOM is complete

Answer (score 0):

I Suggest you to use autorun.
Here is doc: http://docs.meteor.com/#/basic/Tracker-autorun

Comment: I've done it and it didn't help because i didn't do anything with the data inside this.autorun. but just tried again with const url = Router.current().url; inside this.autorun and it work completely!
thx a lot!